# How to get the utilization rate of thread's current memory in java interface

Tags: java, threadpool

How to get the utilization rate of thread's current memory in java interface？
What classes and methods do you need to use?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? It's unclear to me. Also, it is a bit of broad and you should also show the results of your research. Please see [ask], thanks.

Comment: I need to dynamically get the memory size of each thread in JVM when the program is running. Then limit the number of threads. Can you get the memory size of a thread in real time?thank you

Comment: That's more information, good. Please [edit] your question to improve it. And share the results of your own research to this topic. StackOverflow demands a relative high standard for questions and answers (see [ask]).

Comment: I know that there is a way to get the memory size of the current JVM in Java. For example: totalMemory (), maxMemory (), freeMemory (), but these three methods can not meet my needs. What I need is the memory size of a single thread. There is no code implementation now. It's just a simple idea. I can only describe my thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: As @Zabuza has suggested you should research this first before asking here. You also haven't described what you mean by _utilization rate_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is not specifically about the utilization rate of a thread's memory. I am not sure about that.*

I have included here code that I used to pull similar statistics sometime back. Mine is JDK 8 on Windows.

It prints the allocated bytes for the current thread from the local VM.

The code that shows how one could connect to a remote JVM is included only to show that it is possible. But I don't show how to pull the same information from a remote JVM. It should give you some ideas.

Moreover it uses `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean` which I think is generally not recommended. I also don't know how valid the allocated bytes information is when it is actually pulled.

```
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class ThreadProbe{

    /* This code gives an idea about how to access a remote JVM */
    MBeanServerConnection connectJMXRemote(int port){
        JMXServiceURL url;
        MBeanServerConnection remote = null;
        try {
            url = new JMXServiceURL(
                    "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:" + port + "/jmxrmi");
            JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
            remote = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
            System.out.println("Remote JMX connection is successful");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(getStackTrace(e));
        }
        return remote;
    }
    public  void getThreadStatistics() {

        /* This code gives an idea about how to access a remote JVM */
        //MBeanServerConnection mbs = connectJMXRemote(9010);

        ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        System.out.println( ((com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)threadBean).
                                    getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId()) );
    }

    String getStackTrace(Throwable t){
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        t.printStackTrace(pw);
        return sw.toString();

    }

    public static void main( String... argv ){
        ThreadProbe tp =new ThreadProbe();
        tp.getThreadStatistics();
    }
}
```